# Get volumes files from multi part rar file c#

Tags: c#, 7zip, rar, sevenzipsharp, sharpcompress

I have multi-part RAR files in the same folder and I want to check if all parts of the RAR exist.  I am using SharpCompress v0.24, here is my code:

```
using (var archive = RarArchive.Open("D:/Ontology tool.part1.rar"))
{

    foreach (RarVolume vol in archive.Volumes)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(vol.IsMultiVolume + " \n"+ vol.IsFirstVolume+"\n"+ vol.IsSolidArchive);
    }
}
```

But I cannot get the volume full file name.
I then use SevenZipSharp v 0.64 and 7z.dll version 19, here is my code:

```
using (var extractor = new SevenZipExtractor("D:/Ontology tool.part1.rar"))
{
    MessageBox.Show(extractor.VolumeFileNames[0]+"");
}
```

But then I get the error:

> Invalid archive open/read error! Is it encrypted and a wrong
>   password was provided? If your archive is an exotic one, it is
>   possible that SevenZipSharp has no signature for its format and thus
>   decided it is TAR by mistake

Note that the WinRAR program seems it make changes of RAR file formats because I create a RAR file with version 5.71 and when I try to open it with old WinRAR version it not opened ok, I mean files are not in the correct format.

The same applies to SevenZipSharp. If I open an old RAR file I created since 2014 it opens ok, but when I open a RAR file created with WinRAR v 5.71 it raises this error.

So now how can I get all parts files names of multi part RAR file?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any idea of how can I get all parts files names of multi part RAR file

Comment: How to get original rar file name ,not rar part name?

Comment: Ho to get next volume name from rar file part?

Answer (score 0):

I end up using winrar.exe , send command to test file like this:

```
  [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern int SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr point);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

        private const int SW_MAXIMIZE = 3;
        private const int SW_MINIMIZE = 6;
        private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public int showCmd;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMinPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Point ptMaxPosition;
            public System.Drawing.Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
        }
        private enum WindowShowStyle : uint
        {
            /// <summary>Hides the window and activates another window.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_HIDE</remarks>
            Hide = 0,
            /// <summary>Activates and displays a window. If the window is minimized
            /// or maximized, the system restores it to its original size and
            /// position. An application should specify this flag when displaying
            /// the window for the first time.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNORMAL</remarks>
            ShowNormal = 1,
            /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it as a minimized window.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMINIMIZED</remarks>
            ShowMinimized = 2,
            /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED</remarks>
            ShowMaximized = 3,
            /// <summary>Maximizes the specified window.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_MAXIMIZE</remarks>
            Maximize = 3,
            /// <summary>Displays a window in its most recent size and position.
            /// This value is similar to "ShowNormal", except the window is not
            /// actived.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE</remarks>
            ShowNormalNoActivate = 4,
            /// <summary>Activates the window and displays it in its current size
            /// and position.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOW</remarks>
            Show = 5,
            /// <summary>Minimizes the specified window and activates the next
            /// top-level window in the Z order.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_MINIMIZE</remarks>
            Minimize = 6,
            /// <summary>Displays the window as a minimized window. This value is
            /// similar to "ShowMinimized", except the window is not activated.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE</remarks>
            ShowMinNoActivate = 7,
            /// <summary>Displays the window in its current size and position. This
            /// value is similar to "Show", except the window is not activated.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWNA</remarks>
            ShowNoActivate = 8,
            /// <summary>Activates and displays the window. If the window is
            /// minimized or maximized, the system restores it to its original size
            /// and position. An application should specify this flag when restoring
            /// a minimized window.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_RESTORE</remarks>
            Restore = 9,
            /// <summary>Sets the show state based on the SW_ value specified in the
            /// STARTUPINFO structure passed to the CreateProcess function by the
            /// program that started the application.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_SHOWDEFAULT</remarks>
            ShowDefault = 10,
            /// <summary>Windows 2000/XP: Minimizes a window, even if the thread
            /// that owns the window is hung. This flag should only be used when
            /// minimizing windows from a different thread.</summary>
            /// <remarks>See SW_FORCEMINIMIZE</remarks>
            ForceMinimized = 11
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);


        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetParent(IntPtr hWnd);

        const int SW_RESTORE = 9;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr Handle, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool repaint);

        static readonly int GWL_STYLE = -16;
        static readonly int WS_VISIBLE = 0x10000000;

....
 private string GetMissingCompressedFile(string FilePath, string WinRARPath)
        {
            string MissingCompressedFile = "";
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = WinRARPath;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            // -ibck -inul
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = " t " + " \"" + FilePath + "\"";
            //p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
           // p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            //p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            //p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

            IntPtr PanelHandler=new IntPtr();
            WinRARPanel_Ref.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                PanelHandler = WinRARPanel_Ref.Handle;
            });

            p.Start();

            IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;

            while (true)
            {
                if (p.HasExited)
                    break;
                if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                    break;

                    Thread.Sleep(100); // Don't hog the CPU
                p.Refresh(); // You need this since `MainWindowHandle` is cached

            }
                if (!p.HasExited)
                {
                    SetParent(p.MainWindowHandle, PanelHandler);
                    //SetWindowLong(p.MainWindowHandle, GWL_STYLE, WS_VISIBLE);
                    //MoveWindow(p.MainWindowHandle, 0, 0, WinRARPanel_Ref.Width, WinRARPanel_Ref.Height, true);
                }


            while (!p.HasExited)
            {
                var _windowHandle = FindWindow(null, "Next volume is required");
                var _parent = GetParent(_windowHandle);
                if (_parent == p.MainWindowHandle)
                {
                    if (!p.HasExited)
                    {
                        SetParent(_windowHandle, WinRARPanel_Ref.Handle);
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    if (!p.HasExited)
                        {

                        MainForm_Ref.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {     
                            Clipboard.Clear();


                            ShowWindow(h, SW_RESTORE);
                            SetForegroundWindow(h);
                            SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)");
                            string ClipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClipboardText))
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    string n = new FileInfo(ClipboardText).Name;

                                    MissingCompressedFile = ClipboardText;

                                    if (!p.HasExited)
                                    {
                                        p.Kill();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    if (ClipboardText.Contains("You need to start extraction from a previous volume to unpack"))
                                    {
                                        MissingCompressedFile = "";
                                        p.Kill();
                                    }
                                }

                                Clipboard.Clear();
                            }
                        });

                        }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!p.HasExited)
                    {

                        MainForm_Ref.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                        {
                            Clipboard.Clear();

                            if (!p.HasExited)
                            {
                                ShowWindow(h, SW_RESTORE);
                                SetForegroundWindow(h);
                            }
                            SendKeys.SendWait("^(c)");
                            string ClipboardText = Clipboard.GetText();
                            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClipboardText))
                            {

                                try
                                {
                                    string n = new FileInfo(ClipboardText).Name;

                                    MissingCompressedFile = ClipboardText;

                                    if (!p.HasExited)
                                    {
                                        p.Kill();
                                    }
                                }
                                catch
                                {
                                    if (ClipboardText.Contains("You need to start extraction from a previous volume to unpack"))
                                    {
                                        MissingCompressedFile = "";
                                        p.Kill();
                                    }
                                }

                                Clipboard.Clear();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }
            }

            if (!p.HasExited)
            {
                p.Kill();
            }
            p = null;

            return MissingCompressedFile;
        }
```